# How i can insert my data PHP with multi aray

Tags: php, sql

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
<!-- Student 1 -->
Student Name :<input type="text" name="stname[]">
Phone:<input type="text" name="phone[]">
Sex:<input type="text" name="sex[]">
Address:<input type="text" name="address[]">

<!-- Student 2 -->
Student Name :<input type="text" name="stname[]">
Phone:<input type="text" name="phone[]">
Sex:<input type="text" name="sex[]">
Address:<input type="text" name="address[]">
</form>
```

How I can insert it into my table tbl_student?

Comment: Don't expect others do you homework

Comment: @Fabio : Instead he would be learning :D :P

Comment: user for loop for this

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai he's creating an array of each input

Comment: Yes...you can do that by foreach/for loop..! :D

Comment: A whole working code snippet gift from my side : http://pastebin.com/95qxhQpb

Comment: @Fabio : My bad..I didn't get a good look at the code and went off posting comment..!

Comment: has ha answer on bellow help full xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should get data from $_POST as an array.

```
foreach($_POST['stname'] as $i => $name) {
  $phone = $_POST['phone'][$i];
  $sex = $_POST['sex'][$i];
  $address = $_POST['address'][$i];
  // Do something with data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this also

```
if (isset($_POST)) {
    $data = $_POST;

    $names = $data['stname'];

    foreach($names as $key => $n) {
        $name = $n;
        $phone = $data['phone'][$key];
        $sex = $data['sex'][$key];
        $add = $data['address'][$key];

        echo 'name: ' . $name;
        echo 'phone: ' . $phone;
        echo 'sex: ' . $sex;
        echo 'add: ' . $add;
        echo '<br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Brother This Code help me a lots